# MySQL: Which is smaller, storing 2 sets of similar data in 1 table vs 2 tables (+indexes)?

Tags: mysql

I was asked to optimize (size-wise) statistics system for a certain site and I noticed that they store 2 sets of stat data in a single table. Those sets are product displays on search lists and visits on product pages. Each row has a product id, stat date, stat count and stat flag columns. The flag column indicates if it's a search list display or page visit stat. Stats are stored per day and product id, stat date (actually combined with product ids and stat types) and stat count have indexes.

I was wondering if it's better (size-wise) to store those two sets as separate tables or keep them as a single one. I presume that the part which would make a difference would be the flag column (lets say its a 1 byte TINYINT) and indexes. I'm especially interested about how the space taken by indexes would change in 2 table scenario. The table in question already has a few millions of records.

I'll probably do some tests when I have more time, but I was wondering if someone had already challenged a similar problem.

Comment: I would suggest doing some tests, as you suggest.

Comment: Can you show the create table statement for the current table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a moment to conduct a test. It was just a small scale test with 12k and 48k records.

The table that stored both types of data had following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stat_test` (
`id_off` int(11) NOT NULL,
`stat_date` date NOT NULL,
`stat_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
`stat_type` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_off`,`stat_date`,`stat_type`),
KEY `id_off` (`id_off`),
KEY `stat_count` (`stat_count`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin2;
```

The other two tables had this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stat_test_other` (
`id_off` int(11) NOT NULL,
`stat_date` date NOT NULL,
`stat_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_off`,`stat_date`),
KEY `id_off` (`id_off`),
KEY `stat_count` (`stat_count`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin2;
```

In case of 12k records 2 separate tables were actually slightly bigger than the one storing everything, but in case of 48k records, two tables were smaller and by a noticeable value.

In the end I didn't split the data into two tables to solve my initial space problem. I managed to considerably reduce the size of the database, by removing the redundant `id_off` index and adjusting the data types (in most cases `unsigned smallint` was more than enough to store all the values I needed). Note that originally `stat_type` was also of type `int` and for this column `unsigned tinyint` was enough. All in all this reduced the size of the database from 1.5GB to 600MB (and my limit was just 2GB for the database). Another advantage of this solution was the fact that I didn't have to modify a single line of code to make everything work (since the site was written by someone else, I didn't had to spend hours trying to understand the source code).

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, if two kinds of observations are conformable, it's best to keep them in a single table.  By "conformable," I mean that their basic data is the same.

It seems that your observations are indeed conformable.

Why is this?

First, you can add more conformable observations trivially easily. For example, you could add sales to search-list and product-page views, by adding a new value to the flag column.

Second, you can report quite easily on combinations of the kinds of observations. If you separate these things into different tables, you'll be doing UNIONs or JOINs when you want to get them back together.

Third, when indexing is done correctly the access times are basically the same.

Fourth, the difference in disk space usage is small. You need indexes in either case.

Fifth, the difference in disk space cost is trivial. You have several million rows, or in other words, a dozen or so gigabytes. The highest-quality Amazon Web Services storage costs about US$ 1.00 per year per gigabyte. It's less than the heat for your office will cost for the day you will spend refactoring this stuff.  Let it be.